# How to suppress List item based on the input value in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class with a set of properties as given below.

```
class CustomerInfo
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string PostCode{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Email{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a method called `getinfo(string Fields)` which take string field names as parameters like below “FirstName, LastName, Title” based on the parameter fields my method should return only the list with

```
<CustomerInfo>
<FirstName></FirstName>
<LastName></LastName>
<Title></Title>
</CustomerInfo>
```

How can I do this in c#?

```
Public List<CustomerInfo>  getinfo(string Fields)
{
List<CustomerInfo>  list = new List<CustomerInfo> ();
…….
return list;
}
```

Please do the needful.

Comment: With some difficulty (if you want to do it in a maintainable way.) Maybe something with reflection.

Comment: if it is maintainable soln. then it is fine.

Comment: @user995099, may be you should get an string[] as parameter for your getinfo(). Because if it's only string how can you return a list based on that.

Comment: Are you trying to copy across property values or change the properties of declared in the returned CustomerInfo?

Comment: @skk, what would be the solution if it is string[]

Comment: then based on the string array you can filter the properties present in the Customerinfo class. In the string[] you can pass more than one property name.

Comment: @skk, Could you please give me the sample code?

Comment: @user995099, finally you want to send the values of assigned properties? or only property names based on input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something with refletion like this.  I haven't tried to compile this, but it should be pretty close.

```
List<CustomerInfo>  inList = new List<CustomerInfo> ();
List<CustomerInfo>  outList = new List<CustomerInfo> ();

string[] properties = string.split(',');
foreach(var info in inList)
{
    CustomerInfo filteredInfo = new CustomerInfo();
    foreach(var property in properties)
    {  
       var pi = typeof(CustomerInfo).GetProperty(property);
       pi.SetValue(filteredInfo, pi.GetValue(info, null), null);
    }
    outList.Add(filteredInfo);
}

return outList;
```